# Suppress / handle type errors in Angular for interpolated data

Tags: angular, typescript, class

I have some html that interpolates data from my component.ts, like

```
<div>
    {{currentData.property}}
</div>
```

Where currentData is a variable of type Data, which I made a class for. My component.ts looks something like this

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  cookie:any;
  currentData:Data;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private utilService: UtilService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cookie = this.utilService.getCookie();
    if(this.cookie != ""){
      this.callServices()
    }else{
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    }
  }

  callServices(){
    this.currentData = await this.apiService.getData();
  }
```

My problem is more of a nuisance than anything. Everything functions as it should, but Angular bombards my console with errors because there is no property "property" on currentData, which is undefined. Once my API calls come through, the data goes where it should and I get no errors.

How do I get rid of these errors? Moreso, is there a best practice way of doing this that I'm missing here?

Comment: Safe navigation `{{currentData?.property}}`

Comment: @AshishRanjan perfect- thank you! I also, especially for my purposes, found wrapping everything in an *ngIf to work fine